# Proper use of double & single quotes, concatecating periods, and commas

Tags: php, syntax

Pretty new to PHP, trying to figure out proper syntax for concatecating variables and such into strings.

For example:

```
A    $mydir = "../../uploads/images/'".$id."'/thumb"; 

B    $mydir = "../../uploads/images/".$id."/thumb"; 

C    $mydir = '../../uploads/images/'.$id.'/thumb"; 

D    $mydir = "../../uploads/images/$id/thumb";
```

Which one is correct?

What about when you end a string with a variable, but have to comma out to define the next element?

```
    mkdir('../../uploads/images/' . $newid , 0777);
```

What about when the variable is in the middle?

```
    mkdir('../../uploads/images/' . $newid . '/thumb', 0777);
```

Lastly, can anyone recommend a good resource for PHP reference? W3Schools isn't cutting it...

Comment: W3Schools is a bad reference altogether, http://php.net

Comment: You have a syntax mistake in C, should be `$mydir = '../../uploads/images/'.$id.'/thumb'; `

Answer (score 3):

Strings in PHP can use either double or single quotes.  There is a difference between the two, in that using double quotes will cause PHP to interpolate any variables in the string.  For instance:

```
$var = 'test';
echo "This is a $var";  // outputs: This is a test

echo 'This is a $var'; // outputs: This is a $var
```

Because of this, using double quotes around your strings is a bit slower, since the string must be interpolated by PHP before it can be output.  There is also nowdoc and heredoc support for strings in PHP, as well.

Aside from that distinction there is no difference and you can use them interchangeably, as in the following example:

```
echo 'I like ' . "concatenating" . ' strings';
```

It is probably a good idea, though, to be consistent throughout your code.  For more information, please refer to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: Covers everything, I wanted to put in my answer +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

Go to the PHP Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

As for the different types of strings:

If you use the double-quoted strings, you can include variables inside of the string like this:

```
$name = "world";
print("Hello $name");
```

Single Quotes will not expand variables.

The period is just the concatenation operator. So if you end by concatenating a variable that's fine. I.e. this is ok:

```
 $name = "world";
 $greeting = "Hello ".$name;
```

Answer (score 1):

B and D are correct. The only difference between single and double quotes in PHP is that the content between double quotes is parsed for PHP. From [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing),

> When a string is specified in double quotes or with heredoc,
>   variables are parsed within it.

A -  has a pair of unnecessary single quotes.

B - FINE

C - has an incorrect ending quote. should end in a single quote.

D - FINE

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use your **A** or **B**, if you have double quotes, using **D** is much nicer to read. That is not to say you can't use it, if you like having a hard time reading your strings, go ahead!

The comma after the string doesn't matter

```
mkdir('../../uploads/images/' . $newid , 0777); // works
mkdir('../../uploads/images/' . $newid . '/thumb', 0777); // works too
mkdir("../../uploads/images/$newid" , 0777); // works and is nicer to read
mkdir("../../uploads/images/$newid/thumb", 0777); // also nicer to read
```

If the value you want in the string is not a variable, you either have to create a variable, or you have to use regular string concatenation (instead of interpolation)

Answer (score 0):

for concatenation B or C will both work, however for relative file paths it's usually best to use the

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

syntax, and access your files relative to your server's html root folder, meaning your syntax will look something like

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/folder/foler/".$id."/thumb";
```

Answer (score 0):

A won't do it.

B is the best.

C has a syntax mistake. Moreover, for strings you generally use `"`, but on the other hand, `'` is used when formatting html like: `'<a href="google.com">Google!</a>'` so you don't need to escape quotes and the code looks nice.

D works, but not recommended. For example in D `"blah $this -> name blah" won't work. That is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

from your choice list, 'B' is fine, so is 'D'.  My favorite reference is the official manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/